# Roadblock using template functions

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, c++

As part of a larger project, I'm trying to create a simple template function that will take an array and a value, both of the same type, and fill the array with the value. I'm running into the error quoted below:

"specializing member '::Fill_With' requires 'template<>' syntax"

Below is the offending code fragment:

```
// Simple function to fill an array with a specified value.
template <class T> void Fill_With(T target_array, T value){
    int Array_Size = sizeof(target_array) / sizeof(T);
    for(int l = 0; l < Array_Size; ++l){
        target_array[l] = value;
    }
}

int array1[4] = {1,2,3,4}, k = 0;
Fill_With<int>(array1, k);
```

I've read numerous other forum posts on the error message, but haven't quite been able to figure out what I'm missing. I've read that I need to include a blank "template<>" header before the function declaration but that didn't seem to solve the issue.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: See this SO question: [How to write a template function that takes an array and an int specifying array size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33234979/669576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by getting rid of the templates, as they make things more confusing. In the following, I replaced `T` with `int`.

```
void Fill_With(int target_array, int value){
    int Array_Size = sizeof(target_array) / sizeof(int);
    for(int l = 0; l < Array_Size; ++l){
        target_array[l] = value;
    }
}
```

Let's try it out! I pasted this into the Arduino IDE and compiled it. Here is the output:

```
sketch_aug01a/sketch_aug01a.ino: In function 'void Fill_With(int, int)':
sketch_aug01a:4: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
         target_array[l] = value;
                       ^
exit status 1
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
```

This is telling us that we're trying to subscript (that's the term for the `[]` syntax) a variable of type `int` with a variable of type `int`. In C++, a pointer to the start of an array has type `int *`, not `int`. Let's fix the type of `target_array` in the function signature:

```
void Fill_With(int *target_array, int value){
```

It compiles, but if you ran it you would quickly run into a bug:

- When given an expression, the [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) will return the number of bytes in the type of the expression. The type of the expression `target_array` is `int *`, so `sizeof(target_array) == sizeof(int *)`. On 32-bit systems, `sizeof(int *) == 32/8 == 4`.
- When given a type, the `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes in the type. So `sizeof(int)` gives the number of bytes in an `int`, which is [guaranteed to be at least 2 bytes (16 bits)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties), but is usually 4 or 8 (it depends on the system).

Together, this means that `Array_Size` ends up being some small number like 0 or 1, regardless of the contents of `target_array`. To fix this, you can instead pass in the length of the array as a parameter:

```
void Fill_With(int *target_array, int array_size, int value){
    for(int l = 0; l < array_size; ++l){
        target_array[l] = value;
    }
}

int array1[4] = {1,2,3,4}, k = 0;
Fill_With(array1, 4, k);
```

Now you can put the templates back in:

```
template <class T> void Fill_With(T *target_array, int array_size, T value){
    for(int l = 0; l < array_size; ++l){
        target_array[l] = value;
    }
}

int array1[4] = {1,2,3,4}, k = 0;
Fill_With<int>(array1, 4, k);
```

By the way, C++ already has this function built in. It's called [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill). Here's how to use it:

```
#include <algorithm>

int array1[4] = {1,2,3,4}, k = 0;
std::fill(array1, array1 + 4, k);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed explanation. I'm still pretty noobish so the breakdown was great.
FYI, after some tinkering and research, it does not appear that <algorithm> or std::fill are supported by Arduino, which is kind of a bummer. Thankfully I can just create the template function the correct way.